# ¿Cómo elimino los valores negativos del Grafico?

Tags: r, rstudio, ggplot2

¿Cómo elimino los valores negativos del Grafico? (es comparativo)

¿Cómo elimino los puntos a los nombres de los ejes? (me sale error si los borro)

Mi código actual es:

```
library(reshape2)
library(plyr)
require(RColorBrewer)
library(ggplot2)

sexcafe<- read.csv("sexcaf.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";")
sexcafe$Macho<--1*sexcafe$Machosexcafe$Rango.peso<-factor(sexcafe$Rango.peso, levels = sexcafe$Rango.peso,labels = sexcafe$Rango.peso)
sexcafe.melt<-melt(sexcafe, value.name = 'Numero.de.individuos',variable.name = 'sexo',id.vars = 'Rango.peso')

pirsexo <- ggplot(sexcafe.melt, aes(x = Rango.peso, y = Numero.de.individuos, fill = sexo))+
   geom_bar(data = subset (sexcafe.melt, sexo == "Macho"), stat = "identity")+
   geom_bar(data = subset (sexcafe.melt, sexo == "Hembra"), stat="identity")+
   scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-200, 200, 50))+
   ggtitle("CP")+
   coord_flip()+
   Tema

pirsexo
```

El resultado actual es:

[image: imagen]

La tabla de datos es:

[image: tabla]

Comment: Bienvenida Michelle Alexandra a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Borrar valores negativos: ¿a qué te refieres? ¿Borrar las observaciones para la categoría "Macho"? ¿Quitar las etiquetas del eje x que son negativas? ¿Mostrarlas como positivas? Puntos en los nombres de los ejes ¿Quitar los decimales en las etiquetas del eje y? Igualmente hay algo raro en los rangos por que hay huecos entre rangos, ¿eso está bien?

Answer (score 0):

Ya que tienes definida la escala del eje con `scale_y_continuous()` puedes crear la mismas secuencia en valor absoluto y establecerla como la etiqueta a mostrar mediante el parámetro `labels`:

```
scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-200, 200, 50), 
                   labels = abs(seq(-200, 200, 50))
```